# Postgres ERROR: row is too big

Tags: database, postgresql

```
psql (9.2.7)
Type "help" for help.
postgres=# \c dtb_dpx
You are now connected to database "dtb_dpx" as user "postgres".
dtb_dpx=# vacuum full;
ERROR:  row is too big: size 4674072, maximum size 8160
dtb_dpx=#
```

What can be done ? Any idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: please update post with result of `vacuum full verbose instead;` I need to check the storage option for the column, that results error

Comment: Looks a lot like data corruption. Try restoring your oldest backup on a different system and see if it has the same problem. 9.2.7 is old and lacks a lot of bugfixes, maybe there is a connection.